# datetime searching using sub-sections of the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM string

Tags: mysql, datetime, search

[MySQL/PHP] My table has a `date` column of `datetime` format. All records are of the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` variety.

MySQL queries like `SELECT record FROM table WHERE date > '1941' AND date < '1945'` work nicely.

MySQL queries like `SELECT record FROM table WHERE date > '1941-03-01' AND date < '1945-01-30'` also work nicely.

But what about if I wanted all records that were filed in March, regardless of year? Or all records filed on the 17th, regardless of month/year?

``SELECT record FROM table WHERE date = '03'` clearly doesn't work.

I know I could snag it with a `LIKE '%-03-%'` parameter, but that doesn't leave room for me to search for range, like all records from March to May.

Help? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html, you will find many useful functions for your purpose. 
`... WHERE MONTH(date) = 3`, e.g. =)

Answer (score 2):

Try `` WHERE MONTH(DATE(`date`)) BETWEEN '03' AND '05' ``

The `DATE()` part is to extract the date from the timestamp to be used with `MONTH()`.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but giving the check to Jens since he was the first to provide a link back to the docs. Thank you!

Comment: Aw ): dang I wanted to be the answer xD

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL date functions:

```
SELECT record FROM table WHERE MONTH(date) = 3
SELECT record FROM table WHERE DAY(date) = 17
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: +1 for you too, but giving the check to Jens because he was a few seconds faster. Thank you!